# Error when checking model input: expected flatten_input_8 to have 4 dimensions

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am getting following error when I run this code:

> Error when checking model input: expected flatten_input_8 to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (3167, 1)

My code:

```
lines=[]

with open('train_data/driving_log.csv') as csvFile:
    reader= csv.reader(csvFile)
    for line in reader:
        lines.append(line)



images=[]
measurements=[]
for line in lines:
    source_path=line[0]
    file_name= source_path.split('/')[-1]
    current_path= 'train_path/IMG/' + file_name
    image= cv2.imread(current_path)
    images.append(image)
    measurement=float(line[3])
    measurements.append(measurement)

X_train=np.array(images)
y_train=np.array(measurements)

model= Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(160,320,3)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_split=0.2,shuffle=True)
model.save('model.h5')
```

Any idea what is wrong in my code? please help me to solve this, thanks

Comment: For some reason the shape of your 'X' is not the one you expected. Could you print out first row of `X_train`?

Comment: The flatten layer should have four dimensions. In short, the shape of X_train should be `(batchSize, 3, 160, 320)` if using Theano and `(batchSize,160,320,3)` if using Tensorflow as the backend. You must be having only three dmensions. Even if you have only one sample, the shape of `X_train` should be `(1,160,320,3)`.

Comment: You probably want np.ndarray instead of np.array

Comment: Thanks guys for your prompt response, I found out the problem, problem is with my file path to the image folder, thank very much @MarcinMożejko your first comment made me to check the X_train and I found no data in that. Thanks everyone.